# On which data is the ASSERTION CHECK in SQL used?

Tags: sql, assertion

I'm trying to understand the workflow behind the `ASSERTION CHECK` function of SQL.

I have to write an `ASSERTION`, which would make it impossible to book a room in a hotel, if there are not enough rooms left.

Now I imagine that I use a `INSERT` command to create a dataset in which I book 50 rooms of a hotel, which has 30 rooms left.

```
CREATE ASSERTION overbooked
CHECK (EXISTS (SELECT (Hotel.NumberOfRooms -
    SUM(Bookings.AmountOfBookedRooms)) AS 'RoomsLeft'
FROM Hotel INNER JOIN Bookings ON Hotel.HotelID = Bookings.HotelID
WHERE RoomsLeft > 'Amount of rooms in the created bookings-dataset'))
```

Now my problem is understanding, at which time this whole `CHECK` occurs.

I can't really even articulate my problem.

How do I include the dataset I am trying to create in the `ASSERTION`?

If the rule only checks the existing data for if there are more than 0 rooms left, I could still have a person book 5 rooms in a hotel with only 1 room left.

So when I create a dataset, does the `ASSERTION CHECK` test for the rule, if the inserted data would be placed in the table, would this rule hold?

I hope I'm using the `ASSERTION correctly`.

Comment: I think i might have gotten the assertion wrong in the end: I think I can just say:
ASSERTION overbooked CHECK 
(SELECT SUM(Bookings.AmoutOfRooms) AS 'Booked' 
FROM Bookings INNER JOIN Hotel ON Bookings.HotelID = Hotel.ID 
WHERE Booked > Hotel.Capacity)

Comment: . . You need to tag the question with the database you are using.  Most databases do not support assertions.